# How can I share columns between different tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I store multiple types of entities in separate tables in my database. All those entities (EDIT: each row separately) can be synced to a server and I would like to keep track of which entities to sync and their status in an easy to update and easy to query fashion.

At the moment, I have considered the following approaches:

1. Add the columns to each table separately

   - This results in really ugly queries
   - The maintainability is quiet bad
2. Make the entity IDs unique across tables and have a separate table for the extra information

   - This would be easier to maintain
   - I would somehow need to enforce database wide uniqueness

This results in the following questions:

1. Is there another solution that I missed?
2. For (1), is there a concept that makes it easier to maintain those columns?
3. For (2), how can I enforce database wide uniqueness?

Comment: I just wanted to add, that I'm not really happy with solution 2 either, because I like the fact, that IDs are "type safe".

Comment: Do you need to sync entities or individual rows within each entity? Have you considered a 'watermark' table that has a two-column key: 1) The name of one of your primary tables, and 2) The status of that table?

Comment: @Ben I'm sorry for the unclarity. I would like to sync single rows.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Your tables represent entities. This is typical for a database. Customer, product and order are different entities and have each their own table. You want to sync with a server. Is this one-way or two-way, i.e. does the server get the update from the client or are their multiple clients that must update from the server, too? You could have a create_time and an last_update_time in each table, so as to see which rows have been added or changed since __. This wouldn't cover deletes, though, so if there can be deletes, you need a separate log table instead...

Comment: ... You are considering a log table, but there you'd store the table name and the row's ID, which you cannot secure with a foreign key of course. The only solution to this would be a master table for entity IDs and the other tables would reference that entity ID. Yes? This is your dilemma? Well, with the entity table, how to ensure that not two rows in different tables have the same entity ID? The DBMS cannot guarantee this either, so you'd buy one assurance buy selling another :-( I'd stick with the first, simpler approach and don't have an entity table.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Client and server are relatively independent in my architecture, so the client can have different data than the server (for the same ID). But for some rows it may decide to keep them in sync with the server and upload changes. I need to store which rows (across all tables) should be synced and whether they were already synced (to the server in that case).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner And I think maybe you are right and I should have those fields seperate for each entity. Proper constraints are more important than a simple interface probably.